# Excel formula to extract file name from paths without file extension

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have this excel formula which I'm hoping can be amended to extract the file name **without the file extension**. I know this can be done over two formulas but it would make the process I am working with a whole lot easier. I'm also trying to avoid `VBA` as I don't have any knowledge on it.

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))+1,LEN(A1)),"")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have logic for finding the position of the last "\" character in string. You can use the same logic for finding the position of the last "." character in string. Then the difference of those two numbers minus one will be the length of the file name without the file extension. Use this length for the num_chars argument ot the MID function. For example...

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))-1),"")
```

Note that this formula assumes that all file names have an extension. If some files have no extension then you would need to add extra logic to the formula.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Just modified slightly for Mac which uses forward slashes: `=IFERROR(MID(A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",CHAR(1),LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",""))))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))))-1),"")`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you expect A1 to contain the filename, but you can do this all at once if you're willing to replace every instance of "A1" with Cell("filename",A1). Either way, it looks like you are overcomplicating the situation by looking to count the number of file paths, when really all you need is the "[" & "]" which encloses the name of the file.

If A1 is any random cell with nothing special in it, the formula looks like this:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))+1,FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1)
```

If A1 holds CELL("filename",B1), then the formula looks like this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("[",A1)+1,FIND("]",A1)-FIND("[",A1)-1)
```

CELL("filename",B1) looks at B1, and pulls the property "filename". In this case, it doesn't matter whether you use B1, Z10, etc. - it just can't be a circular reference. You can also use CELL to pull cell-specific info, such as cell address etc.

Then the MID function simply looks at A1, starts 1 after the "[", and picks up all the characters up to the "]".